# How to play unity 3d scene inside android application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I need to play unity 3d scene inside my android application.

There will be normal activity which will trigger separate activity inside application to play unity 3d scene.

Anybody know how to integrate unity 3d player inside android application?

Comment: Any luck with this? Would love an update if you ended up solving it :)

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem a little more.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

Build your Unity project as android and then import it as a LIBRARY in the other android application

[Tutorial Here](https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a)

Option 2:

Use a webview in android that supports WebGL ( >v36) and embed your Unity WebGL build inside it.